# .NET Framework for network data packet parsing/assembling?

Tags: .net, parsing, packet

when programming Tcp/IP program, we often will do data packet assembling and parsing, so is there a framework to make our life easier?

I know this is hard to implement.

**Edit:** 
to clarify:

1. application level packet
2. it may need to talk to c++ application, so .net serialization is not applicable.

Comment: What do you actually want to parse? IP packet headers? Or just (possible binary) content of the TCP stream?

Comment: @Miroslav, application level packet.

Answer (score 3):

[Pcap.NET](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/) may be what you're after:

> Pcap.Net is a .NET wrapper for WinPcap
>   written in C++/CLI and C#.
>   It features
>   almost all WinPcap features and
>   includes a packet interpretation
>   framework.

Comment: Thanks Jon, you always answer so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use your own application protocol, [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) might be the right tool to use.

Otherwise it depends on the protocol you are dealing with. For MIME based protocols you can leverage [Sharp MIME tools](http://anmar.eu.org/projects/sharpmimetools/).

Answer (score 0):

Sharppcap, http://sharppcap.sf.net also provides this functionality and supports a wide range of packet types. Also works on windows, mac and Linux.